# Building a dam in a bed

Tags: watering, raised-beds

I put my peppers and cucumbers in the same bed, and it appears that I am overwatering my peppers. It'd be preferable to not remove any plants, as I don't have room. Is there an advisable way to build a dam in my garden bed to keep the plants separate? My first instinct is to shove in a thin piece of plywood but I'm afraid that the glue will leach into the soil.

Answer (score 2):

Dig some holes in the cucumber side. You can leave them bare or line them by inserting terra-cotta pots. Water those holes.

Simply mounding earth can also work, but holes are more fool-proof.